# How to display a shortcode caption somewhere other than the_content

Tags: images, attachments, captions, shortcode, filters

I want to disable shortcode captions for posts in one of my themes, and display the content elsewhere, such as in a sidebar.

The images aren't uploaded to wordpress, but they're linked-to using the post editor's add an image -> from URL functionality resulting in the following shortcode:

```
[caption id="" align="alignnone" width="300" caption="Leonard Nimoy has done far more thing than just play Mr. Spock"]<a href="http://example.com/nimoy"><img src="http://example.com/uploads/nimoy.jpg" alt="Leonard Nimoy in a black suit" title="Leonard Nimoy" width="300" height="228" /></a>[/caption]
```

Any thoughts? I'm assuming using a filter on `img_caption_shortcode` somehow, but I don't know if that's the way to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$caption_info = array();

add_filter( 'img_caption_shortcode', 'capture_caption', 10, 3 );

function capture_caption( $blank = '', $attr, $content ) {

    global $caption_info;

    $caption_info[] = array('attr' => $attr, 'content' => $content );
    return ' ';
}
```

It will save info from all captions into global `$caption_info` variable and suppress their display in content (space is returned because filter result is ignored if empty).

Comment: Sweet. I knew that would work somehow. Should I add a conditional `is_singular()` to this?

Comment: Well, that depends on how exactly you want it to work. In this form it will fire on every call of `img_caption_shortcode()` function that powers `[caption]` and `[wp_caption]` shortcodes. If you want to skip on some conditions - check for them and return empty `''` in function.

Comment: I've put that in, but doing `global $caption_info; var_dump($caption_info);` in my single.php results in `array(0) {}`. Thoughts?

Comment: Dumb moment, but I tripped on that myself, so... Variable is filled only **after** content is displayed and shortcodes run. Are you doing this after `the_content()`?

Comment: I just figured this out myself, and was about to ask that question, lol. Doing this: `$content = apply_filters('the_content',get_the_content());` earlier in the page helps. Then I can simply `echo $content` where `the_content()` would be. It still feels like a hack though. Any way to get that filter to run earlier?

Comment: Probably several ways to handle this. I'd try retrieving content (without assigning to variable) and removing filter from `img_caption_shortcode` so it no longer runs and duplicates info when actual content is displayed. Could also just retrieve content and mine for shortcodes with regex, but could would be completely different thing.